# Speeding tickets issued to foreigners without U.S. driver's licenses

Tags: international, traffic, new-york-state

Just recently, my friends (tourists) and I booked a rental car just for a day trip in New York. Unfortunately, we got caught by a cop for speeding. I showed my foreign driver's license to a cop and my passport. I don't have a driver's license issued by the DMV as I'm still new here in the US (H-4 visa). My friends are tourists and they were in New York for a 2-day visit.

My question is, if I plead guilty, I know they will fine me, but would it somewhat create an impact on my driver's license application if I decided to get a driver's license in the future?

Second question, is the point system still be applicable to me even though I don't have a driver's license yet?

Comment: I added tags and rewrote the title to be more clear. In American English, a traffic ticket for driving at a speed in excess of the speed limit is called a "speeding ticket" rather than an "overspeeding ticket".

Comment: To close voters: this question isn't asking for legal advice; it's asking about possible consequences in a given set of circumstances.

Comment: Canadians are a special case of foreigners. Canadian provinces/territories have a Driver Licence Compact that's very close to the US Driver License Compact, and are therefore integrated into DL and ticket information sharing, just like they were another state.

Comment: In NY, Never plead guilty to speeding unless you have to, in which case the question is moot. Always plead not guilty, and with almost certainty you will get an offer to plead to a lesser offence. E.g. 4 points instead of 6, or 0 points instead of 3.